# Add a select all option to a list of checkboxes in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox, forms

Im relatively new to web development and html forms. In my webapp i have a list (of gpstracks) and each list entry has a checkbox so the user can edit, delete, download, whatever... all selected tracks at once. In order to increase usability i would like to add an "select all" button or checkbox, that automatically checks all other checkboxes in the form (preferably without reloading the entire form).

Is there any possibility at all to do this? I have been trying to use

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($tracks){

        $form = $event->getForm();

        foreach($tracks as $track)
        {
            $form->get($track->getId())->setData(array('checked'=>true));
        }
    }
```

in combination with a second button of the type 'submit' that reads 'select all'. Obviously, this reloads the entire form. But after the reload all checkboxes remain unchecked, so the setData method seems to have no effect at all.

Is there any option to programmatically check checkboxes checkboxes in a form, preferably even without reloading the entire form?

Comment: This would be something you would need javascript (jquery) for.

Comment: I was afraid of that... is it worth it to start with plain javascript or does jquerymake everything significantly easier?

Comment: I don't write much javascript any longer, I use libraries like jQuery, it makes life so much easier. If you don't mind a page reload, you don't need to use Javascript.

Comment: That is good to know... seeing that at one point a reasonably easy-to-use/good looking front end should be added to the project, i guess i'll start looking into the jquery thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery:

```
// cerad.js
Cerad = {};
Cerad.checkboxAll = function(e)
{   
    var nameRoot = $(this).attr('name'); // "refSchedSearchData[ages][]";

    nameRoot = nameRoot.substring(0,nameRoot.lastIndexOf('['));

    var group = 'input[type=checkbox][name^="' + nameRoot + '"]';

    var checked = $(this).prop('checked') ? true : false;

    $(group).prop('checked', checked);
};

{# searchform.html.twig #}
{# form.dates is an array of form check boxes #}
{% if form.dates is defined %}
  {% set items = form.dates %}
  <td>{% include '@CeradGame/Project/Schedule/Twig/ScheduleSearchCheckboxes.html.twig' %}</td>
{% endif %}

{# ScheduleSearchCheckboxes.html.twig #}
{# render one set of check boxes as a table #}
{# Setting a class on the first item #}
<table border="1">
  <tr><th colspan="30">{{ items.vars.label }}</th></tr>
  <tr>
    {% set itemFirst = true %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <td align="center">{{ form_label(item) }}<br />
      {% if itemFirst %}
        {{ form_widget(item, { 'attr': {'class': 'cerad-checkbox-all' }}) }}
        {% set itemFirst = false %}
      {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(item) }}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
    {% endfor %}
  <tr>
</table>

// Grab all the cerad-checkbox-all elements and pass to Cerad.checkboxAll
{% block javascripts %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      // checkbox all functionality
      $('.cerad-checkbox-all').change(Cerad.checkboxAll);
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Using javascript/jquery, no problem indeed! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

1. set html class for checkboxes (in form builder set option attr['class'])
2. add button with other class
3. add event to catch click on button 2, and check checkoxes
   http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/01/how-to-select-all-deselect-checkboxes-jquery